# “Quote by Albert Einstein” or “quote from Albert Einstein”?

Tags: prepositions, quoting

Can both “by” and “from” prepositions be used to indicate the person as the source of quotation?

Is there any difference?

To me “quotes from Albert Einstein” sounds more like “quotes from Albert Einstein's publications”, is that impression correct or not?

Comment: To me, "quote by Albert Einstein" reads as if Einstein is the one doing the quoting.

Comment: A quote "by" Einstein is one he originated, and a quote "from" Einstein is one that comes from him. Unless you specified more, I'd expect them to mean the same thing.

Comment: @Qaz Except that when we are talking about a _work_ rather than a _person_ we always say "from". For example "If music be the food of love" is a quote _from_ Twelfth Night but could either be a quote _from_ or _by_ William Shakespear.